# spark-shell: strange behavior with import

Tags: scala, shell, apache-spark, scala-repl

I am working in a spark-shell (Spark version 2.1.0, Using Scala version 2.11.8, OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, 1.7.0_151).

I import `Column` class:

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
```

I can define a `Column` object:

```
scala> val myCol: Column = col("blah")
myCol: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = blah
```

and use `Column` in a function definition:

```
scala> def myFunc(c: Column) = ()
myFunc: (c: org.apache.spark.sql.Column)Unit
```

So far so good.
But when defining a class, `Column`is not found:

```
scala> case class myClass(c: Column)
<console>:11: error: not found: type Column
       case class myClass(c: Column)
```

However a one-liner works:

```
scala> case class myClass(c: org.apache.spark.sql.Column)
defined class myClass
```

or

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.Column; case class myClass(c: Column)
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
defined class myClass
```

Answer (score 5):

This is [Spark issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-1199).
It works in **Spark 1.6**, but the issue is still present in **Spark 2.1.0 or higher**.

Root cause:

> Classes defined in Shell are inner classes, and therefore cannot be easily instantiated by reflection. They need an additional reference to the outer object, which is non-trivial to obtain.

As a workaround try to use `:paste` in spark-shell.

Comment: Care to explain how these issues are related exactly?